# union de dos arreglos json en uno solo

Tags: javascript, nodejs

como puedo unir dos arreglos json en un solo, ejemplo:

```
array1:[{nombre:noombre, apellido:rodriguez, sexo:masculino }];
array2:[{direccion:direccion, cuidad:ciudad, pais:pais }];
```

y que quede:

`array:[{nombre:noombre, apellido:rodriguez, sexo:masculino, direccion:direccion, cuidad:ciudad, pais:pais }`]

he probado con concat, push y otros y siempre lo trae de esta manera:

```
array:[{nombre:noombre, apellido:rodriguez, sexo:masculino }, {direccion:direccion, cuidad:ciudad, pais:pais }];
```

disculpen si es muy obvia la respuesta estoy comenzando...

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar [`Object.assign( )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), que *importa* los valores de un objeto en otro:

```js
const array1 = [{nombre: 'noombre', apellido: 'rodriguez', sexo: 'masculino' }];
const array2 = [{direccion: 'direccion', cuidad: 'ciudad', pais: 'pais' }];

function zip( arr1, arr2 ) {
    const result = [ ];
    for( let idx = 0; idx < arr1.length; ++idx ) {
        result.push( Object.assign( { }, arr1[idx], arr2[idx] ) )
    }

    return result;
}

console.log( zip( array1, array2 ) );
```

Comment: aqui lo hace pero en mi codigo cuando lo aplico me cambia toda la estructura, igual gracias

Comment: @rrodo1310 Si hubieras puesto un [mcve] sería **mucho más fácil** darte una solución adaptada a tu problema concreto :-)

Comment: Si aqui funciona y en su código no, es porque no planteo bien el problema o hay alguna otra factor involucrado del cual no sabemos... por lo tanto es muy complicado ayudarle sin conocer TODOS los factores que intervienen

Answer (score 3):

Si tienes acceso a una sintaxis mas moderna puedes utilizar el operador de spread y juntar todo en el mismo objeto de la siguiente forma:

```js
const array1 = [{ nombre: 'noombre', apellido: 'rodriguez', sexo: 'masculino' }];
const array2 = [{ direccion: 'direccion', cuidad: 'ciudad', pais: 'pais' }];

const mergedArray = [{ ...array1[0], ...array2[0] }];

console.log(mergedArray);
```

Asi solo necesitas acceder a la primera posicion de cada arreglo (donde esta el objeto que quieres juntar) y luego con el spread operator (...) asignas estos valores a un nuevo objeto, la ventaja de esto es que la sintaxis es mas corta